# How can I add a system service to Android?

Tags: 7.1-nougat, android-wear, services

Me and another person are attempting to enable NFC on the Verizon Wear24. The watch itself has a PN548 NFC chip inside of it and was missing the kernel drivers as well as the NFC service.

We have found some older [answers on SO.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649810/how-to-add-our-own-system-service-in-android-framework) about adding system services (which is what we need to do) but these were written in 2011-2013 (6 years ago as of writing this) and specific to Android 2. Most of the things these answers refer to don't exist on our ROM.

One issue is that we don't have any source to build from -- WearOS is closed source. We can only edit the existing ROM contents.

Comment: You would probably need to build an application that runs a persistent service.. The application starts on every boot and then starts the service...

Comment: See if this is applicable to your situation: [HOW TO ADD CUSTOM INIT SERVICE TO ANDROID?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/207647/218526)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build a system application if you want it to be permanent..  Their is other ways to implement the service, like using init.d and some shell commands to be run at each boot ..

However the easiest method would be to build a simple Auto Start application that starts the service.

I found this answer on SO about building an Auto Start application that also starts a new service...

> [Answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7690600/6116090)

It's fairly easy to build... Once you've built the application, try to install it in the system/app folder and see if everything works... You may have a locked system and can not modify the system apps...

So you will need to use a command list that is run on each boot,... Init.d script should do that.