# Run script using init.rc doesn't work

Tags: scripts, selinux, init.d

I'm trying to run a script that exectues when the device has finished booting. This particular device does not support running scripts from an init.d directory, which is why I am using init.rc.

The init.rc file has been modified to include the following code

```
on property:sys.boot_completed=1
start initAsic

service initAsic /data/local/tmp/runn.sh
user root
group root
oneshot
```

The boot image has then been rebuilt and flashed to the device. The changes can be confirmed by viewing the init.rc file located at `/`

Currently I am only using a simple test script (testScript.sh) which issues the following command

```
echo hi >> /data/local/tmp/test.txt
```

The testScript.sh and text.txt file has `777` permissions set and both have been pushed to the device using `adb push`.
Their current location is `/data/local/tmp/`

For some reason it seems that my script is not running, as I can't see any text being written to test.txt.

Am I missing something? 
Could it be an issue with SELinux?

My device currently has SElinux set to permissive. This was done via altering the BoardConfig.mk file and doing a rebuild of the boot.img.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run an executable on boot and keep it running?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/213353/how-to-run-an-executable-on-boot-and-keep-it-running)

Comment: Add `disabled` keyword to service. After reboot check log: `dmesg | grep -C5 initAsic`.

Comment: Apolgies for the late repsonse and thanks for your suggestions. 

@alecxs I have seen that post and replicated most of the steps in one of the outlined processes but not step for step - the only difference being the locations of the files that are being run. Didn't have any success.

@IrfanLatif I've added the disabled keyword to the servies and ran the dmesg command. It seems that my suscpicon was correct, as it's returning `service initAsic does not have a SELinux domain defined`. I should be able to sort out the issue now - will let you know how I go and post an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By running the command `dmesg | grep -C5 initAsic` I saw that I was getting this error code returned

```
service initAsic does not have a SELinux domain defined
```

The issue what that I needed to add the line `seclabel u:r:init:s0` to my init service as this is a requirement of `init`. The complete service now looks like this. The disabled keyword has also been added as suggested by Irfan.

```
service initAsic2 /data/local/tmp/runn.sh
seclabel u:r:init:s0
user root
group root
oneshot
disabled
```

Also note that SElinux must be set to `permissive` to allow this service to run or  preferably - as setting SElinux to permissive is a security risk - defining the appropriate rules for SElinux and using the modified policy.

More information on the topic here: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/207647/218526

This post was where I found the suggestion to add seclabel property. It also has more useful information regarding the SELinux issue I was encountering: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43600261/init-warning-service-myservice-needs-a-selinux-domain-defined-please-fix

Comment: What's the purpose of adding `seclabel` when you are making SELinux ineffective by setting it `permissive`? Disabling SELinux is a security risk. Instead define context and/or inject proper SELinux rules. See details [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/207647/218526). Or at least use some permissive context like Magisk's for your service only. See my answer to the [question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/213353/218526) marked duplicate by @alecxs.

Comment: tbh @IrfanLatif I'm not sure why it worked. Setting SELinux to permissive should have made it ineffective but for me it seems it did not - I will look into it a bit more to confirm that it wasn't another factor that contributed to it working. I do understand it's a security risk but for my purposes (rapid prototyping) it is ok. In the future I plan to properly define SELinux rules.

Comment: It worked because `seclabel` field is a requirement of `init` that you fulfilled. The point is, `seclabel` is of no use when SELinux is set to `permissive`. It's no more protecting the service or any other file/process.