# SUPolicy to allow custom service to read and write from Internal Storage

Tags: root-access, 9.0-pie, magisk, selinux

I'm setting up custom service with custom `sepolicy` using this as a base:
[How to fix SELinux "avc: denied" errors when launching DNSCrypt as init.d script?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/207484/how-to-fix-selinux-avc-denied-errors-when-launching-dnscrypt-as-init-d-script/207647#207647)

In 99% I follow the quick summary from link 1:1 except some small, irrelevant differences like naming, paths, etc. My issue is that now I want **config** and **log** files to be read and written (respectively) from the internal storage `/sdcard` aka `/storage/self/primary`

Custom **sepolicy** looks like this

```
supolicy --live 'allow init my_service process *'
supolicy --live 'allow my_service my_service * *'
supolicy --live 'allow my_service node tcp_socket { node_bind }'
supolicy --live 'allow my_service node udp_socket { node_bind }'
supolicy --live 'allow my_service port tcp_socket { name_bind name_connect }'
supolicy --live 'allow my_service port udp_socket { name_bind }'
supolicy --live 'allow my_service proc_net file { open read }'
supolicy --live 'allow my_service proc_stat file { read }'
supolicy --live 'allow my_service properties_device dir { read }'
supolicy --live 'allow my_service devpts chr_file { open read write }'
```

`dmesg` shows me permission denials for
`avc: denied { search} [...] scontext=u:r:my_service:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:storage_file:s0 tclass=dir`

How can I update current custom policy I load on boot via:
`exec u:r:magisk:s0 root root -- /system/bin/load_policy /system/etc/selinux/sepolicy`

with new additions? And how would I specify `storage_file`? Does this object covers whole internal sd memory access or I somehow need to specify path?

**UPD:**

I collected all selinux denials and allowed them and now I'm in the clear in terms of selinux permissions. Still, I dont have access to storage, process reports error:

`[FATAL] open /data/media/0/config/my_config.cfg Permission denied`

which makes no sense to me. `chown` for the file is `root/everybody` and `chmod` is `660`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108677/discussion-on-question-by-kirikan-supolicy-to-allow-custom-service-to-read-and-w).