# Private DNS over HTTPS rather than over TLS

Tags: 9.0-pie, dns

The private DNS feature on Android Pie and above doesn't give you the option to select DNS-over-HTTPS (DoH) rather than DNS-over-TLS (DoT). I often connect to a network that doesn't allow traffic on port 853 which is used by DoT. The only solution I found is an app from the Play Store (called Nebulo) that allows you to use DoH but works through a (fake) VPN. Is there a way I can use DoH without a VPN, and possibly without external apps?

Comment: If you are using Cloudflare there's also [1.1.1.1](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cloudflare.onedotonedotonedotone) Android app. It also uses VPN. The only other way is to run a DNS forwarder on phone but it requires root: [How to run DNSCrypt as init.d script?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/207647/218526)